# TensorFlow installation on GeForce 1650 Ti GPU

Tags: nvidia

I bought a machine with Nvidia Geforce GTX 1650ti GPU and now I came to know that it is not listed under the CUDA GPUs.

I want to install TensorFlow on my machine. But I have seen on the web that TF doesn't support 1650ti. Can someone tell me what versions of the TensorFlow, CUDA toolkit, drivers needed to be installed to train my models?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Installed successfully.

Comment: You should ask [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new?assignees=&labels=type%3Abuild%2Finstall&template=10-build-installation-issue.md).

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: @joehoeller Windows

Comment: what version of TF?

Comment: that is sad :(

try to read this forum post https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cuda-enabled-geforce-1650/81010/4 where in they all ALL GPUs are cuda enabled.....

Comment: event this post implies ur GPU should be fine https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/82669/76968

Comment: It seems like you have soled your problem. I would advise you kindly answer your own question so it will be helpful for the community. If anybody would come across this problem then he/she can get guidance from your reply.